# Laravel clean code

Tags: php, laravel

I am writing system for players where I use Laravel freamwork (just for learn) and I have question for more experience developer. I have one function which return me some data to view. I use this function in 3 controllers (but i copy and paste this function to each Controller files) and can I just put this function in one file and then use it in these 3 controllers? How can I use the same function in diffrent controller without copy and past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Base Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class BaseController
{
    protected $playersRepository;

    public function __construct(PlayersRepository $playersRepository)
    {
        $this->playersRepository = $playersRepository;
    }
}
```

Which is injected with a repository object:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class PlayersRepository
{
    public function getPlayers()
    {
        return Player::all();
    }
}
```

Which has a common method, that can be used in more than one extended controller:

**Games**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class Games extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('games', ['players' => $this->playersRepository->getPlayers()]);
    }
}
```

**Matches**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class Matches extends BaseController
{
    public function show()
    {
        return view('matches', [
           'matches' => $matches,

           'players' => $this->playersRepository->getPlayers()
       ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Traits to share methods, however, traits are more usually for describing characteristics and types.

You should create a utility class, or use consider an abstract controller class if this is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Create module (util) or override main Controller class.